# I want to create a label which keeps track of how many times a view controller has been visited

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a table view cell that performs a segue. Now my question is:

I want to put a label that counts how many times a particular view controller has been visited/viewed. Is there anything that we can do to when we click a table cell which performs a segue to another view controller and label in another view controller increments like: 
Visited 1 times,
Visited 2 times,
Visited 3 times.

I did not implement this basic thing, I have something like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    let val2 = mySongsArray[indexPath.row] performSegue(withIdentifier: "JustinTableViewCell" , sender: val2) 
}
```

I am using Swift 3.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have already? If you don't have any you, we're probably not going to be able to help you until you have a specific problem to fix. I'm afraid we can't help with broad requirements like this.

Comment: I did not help this basic thing, I have something like
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let val2 = mySongsArray[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "JustinTableViewCell" , sender: val2)
    }

Comment: I have declared private var count:Int = 0; I want to increment count when ever a table view is selected and update the count value in the label which is in another VC

Comment: You can add this information to your question by pressing the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43137048/edit) button under your question

Comment: Save the `count` value in `NSUserDefault` and it will persist, if you want it gone when your app killed, create a singleton to do it

Comment: @Tj3n I personally don't think using a singleton for this is a good design.

Comment: @Elvin If there's more than tableView and navigation controller, the count will gone when the tableView vc got released, so singleton or global variable is better in this usecase (gone only when app killed)

Comment: @Tj3n I know what you are saying. I'm not saying to not save it when the app is terminated. I'm just saying singleton is too much for this. And most of the time, singleton is bad design. I prefer directly access this number from user defaults.

Comment: @Elvin Of course UserDefault is the way to do here, im just saying for the single use case that can be use singleton so wont need to cares about remove the value from UserDefault, and its nothing bad about singleton, its only bad when putting nonsense in it, maybe you read too much bad post about singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UserDefault.
UserDefault help to store data until application not uninstalled.

Write this code in Second View controller which want count.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let user: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.init()
        var count: Int = user.integer(forKey: "COUNT")
        count += 1
        user.set(count, forKey: "COUNT")
        user.synchronize()

        let Countstr: String = String(count)
        lblCount.text = Countstr
}
```

Comment: Ya, in my app i used noOfTimesLBL

Comment: This solved my problem, but I have five rows of table view cells, these are updating even for other cells.

Comment: then do one thing make key name is cell text

Comment: I did not get you.

Comment: Apply prepare for segue method and set string is cell.textlable.text make it as key if you don't get than comment again i upload code for that.

Comment: I have 5 rows of table view cells. prepare for segue is in MainVC.

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let d = segue.destination as? Justin {
            if let songs = sender as? GreatestHits {
                d.mySongsArray2=songs
            }
        }
    }

i have this in MainVC i want to go to newVC and increment the counter.

Comment: make mySongsArray2 as UserDefault Key

Comment: mySongsArray2 is in FirstVC, I want in secondVC right?

Comment: right then create String Object and store value in prepare segue.

Comment: I have someting like this in MainVC, i have 5 elements. 

mySongsArray.append(linkOne)
        mySongsArray.append(linkTwo)
        mySongsArray.append(linkThree)
        mySongsArray.append(linkFour)
        mySongsArray.append(linkFive)

Comment: Create One String Object and store selected row data in string Object after parse value using prepare segue.

Comment: Can you be more specific? from MainVC ---> SecondVC

Comment: In MainVC Make on String Object and didselectRow method store cell.textlable.text value in String Value

Comment: In SecondVc take string object and store that MainVc String Value and make string as key.

Comment: Or send whole source so i can able  to sort it out.

Comment: But there is no label in MainVC, its only in SecondVC.
Thanks

Comment: I say pass mainVc selected cell value in SecondVC

Answer (score 0):

In your table view controller, you can create counter variables or properties to count the number of time of user tapped the same cell if I correctly understood what you want to achieve.

Notice that I didn't use the phrase `the same` view controller is because let's say, you click on cell A and went to view controller A, and you come back to table view controller, you click on cell A again, the new view controller is not the view controller you just visited any more. The old vc has gone already.

So if you really want to count the number of time that user visited that particular view controller, put a counter in that view controller's `viewDidLoad` method and update it in `viewDidAppear`

if you just want to count the number of time the user entered by tapping that particular cell. count it in your table view controller. update the corresponding counter in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` part

Comment: Wow, let me try.

Comment: Notice that I didn't use the phrase the same view controller is because let's say, you click on cell A and went to view controller A, and you come back to table view controller, you click on cell A again, the new view controller is not the view controller you just visited any more. The old vc has gone already.

I don't want this to happen. I have put count=0 in viewDidLoad() but how I am not getting the logic!.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    var visitCount = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:  "visitCount") as? Int) ?? 0
    visitCount += 1

    self.lblVisitedCount.text = "Page Visited \(visitCount) times"

    UserDefaults.standard.set(visitCount, forKey: "visitCount")
}
```

This will update count and label text everytime the view controller is visited/viewed. If you put the code in viewDidLoad, it will not update count when the VC is visited after getting popped from its next viewController. But, if you do it the way i have told by keeping it in viewWillAppear function, the count will increment everytime the VC appears.

Hope it helped. Cheers :]

Comment: I have 5 rows of data inside table view cell!!